# Use Python to count T's from a list using nested for loops

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to count the number of T's, regardless of case from the provided list, but the code keeps counting every character and returning a value of 46, rather than just counting the T's and returning a value of 6. I also need it to print the strings in which the T's occur.

```
givenStrings = ["Taylor Swift", "Twenty Two", "Georgia Tech"]

count  =0
numTs = 0

for currentString in givenStrings:

    for currentCharacter in currentString:

        if currentCharacter == 't' or 'T':
            numTs+=1
            count = numTs + len(currentString)
            print(count, currentString)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Not really sure what you expected `count = numTs + len(currentString)` to return you...

Comment: Try walking backward through your code and saying out loud what every line does. Or even better, [talk to a rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed the count to: count = numTs + len(currentCharacter) after speaking out loud to myself. This was really by accident, so any explanation you might add about why this fixed the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 3):

Your if condition should be instead:

```
if currentCharacter in ['t','T']:
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would using the brackets be standard for checking the existence in list values?

Answer (score 2):

Change your if condition to

```
if currentCharacter == 't' or currentCharacter =='T':
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be better not to iterate over the characters but to use `sum` with `len` and the string methods `lower` and `count`:

```
count = sum(len(currentString) for currentString in givenStrings)
numTs = sum(currentString.lower().count('t') for currentString in givenStrings)
```

The `sum` function can take any iterable. It sums.

The first applies `len` to each item in the list. Which `sum` consumes to produce a total.

The second uses the `lower` method to convert each of the strings to lowercase and then calls the `count` method to get the number of occurrences of the string `'t'`. Which `sum` consumes to produce a total.

In each of the uses, the argument is a generator expression `(a for b in c)` the parentheses can be omitted when it is the only argument to a function. `sum(a for b in c)` is the same as `sum((a for b in c))`. When it is not the only argument the parentheses are required.

There are other built-in functions that also take iterables most notably `min`, `max`, `any`, `all`. Note that `min` and `max` take a keyword argument `key` such that `max((a for a in b), key=len)` returns the item in the iterable that is the longest. The `heapq.nsmallest` and `heapq.nlargest` functions are effectively natural extensions of `min` and `max`. I'm fond of `any` and `all` especially when combined with `not`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it worked really well! I hate to bother, but would you kindly break down for me what is happening here? Bit of a noob. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way would be to join the array elements into one string, make each character upper case, and then count the upper case `T` character

```
givenStrings = ["Taylor Swift", "Twenty Two", "Georgia Tech"]
print [x.upper() for x in ''.join(givenStrings)].count('T')

> 6
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably do it this way. Forget the nested loop

```
counts = map(lambda x: (x, x.lower().count('t'), ) , givenStrings) 
print(list(counts)) 
numTs = sum(x[1] for x in counts)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm a bit of a noob so I'm not familiar with lambda operations. Look forward to learning more!

Comment: Think of it like an inline function, or just read the official python tutorial